# Hello, I'm new to coding and I was wondering how I can get the output to go horizontally and not vertically

Tags: javascript

```
const animal = "cat";

for (let i = 0; i < animal.length; i++) {
    console.log(animal[i]);
    for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        console.log(j);
    }
}
```

How do I output the answer going straight rather than going down.

Comment: The output meaning the one printed on the console? `console.log` prints an output every time it's called. Maybe store the items you want to log in a variable and then log it at the very end?

Comment: `console.log` breaks a line in the console. That's what it does. HTML is not the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each console.log print in a new line

You can create a variable, assign what you want to display to it then, display it once.

Or

You can use multiple values in one console.log separateb by comma `,`

```js
const animal = "cat";
let result = ""
for (let i = 0; i < animal.length; i++) {
    result += animal[i]
    for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        result += " " + j + " "
        
        console.log(animal[i], j)
    }
}

console.log(result)
```